# Dynamic routes and Membership providers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership

Using the a Membership provider and the MVC framework, is it possible that routes are dynamically changed so that a already logged in user goes to his own page, rather than the default.

At the moment I go to the default. If the user is already logged in or not, there I do a redirect to their own page. This can't be the correct way! Can it?

In RegisterRoutes I have this

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute("Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a Route Constraint.

```
public class AuthenticatedConstraint : IRouteConstraint  
{  
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)  
    {  
        return httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated;  
    }  
}
```

Then you could define a "LoggedInDefault" route before the regular default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "LoggedInDefault", 
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
  new { controller = "LoggedIn", action = "Index", id = "" }, 
  new { loggedIn= new AuthenticatedConstraint()}
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", 
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```